# In Jasper report how to create report pdf using subreport for XML datasource

Tags: java, xml, jasper-reports, datasource, subreport

I have report with 2 sub-reports in which the XML is:
Its as per this linK [Link to create subreport](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/use-subreport-report-which-connected-xml-datasource)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Report runDate="24/04/2014">
    <TransactionTypeRowSet count="3">
        <Row index="0">
            <TransactionType>Funding</TransactionType>
            <TransactionNo>50</TransactionNo>
            <TotalAmount>55210</TotalAmount>
            <TotalFee>530</TotalFee>
            <TotalCommission>250</TotalCommission>
        </Row>
        <Row index="1">
            <TransactionType>Person To Person</TransactionType>
            <TransactionNo>75</TransactionNo>
            <TotalAmount>78000</TotalAmount>
            <TotalFee>780</TotalFee>
            <TotalCommission>350</TotalCommission>
        </Row>
        <Row index="2">
            <TransactionType>Load Float</TransactionType>
            <TransactionNo>30</TransactionNo>
            <TotalAmount>3000</TotalAmount>
            <TotalFee>0</TotalFee>
            <TotalCommission>0</TotalCommission>
        </Row>
    </TransactionTypeRowSet>
    <TransactionRowSet count="2">
        <Row index="0">
            <TransactionId>9535789377931</TransactionId>
            <Date>17-APR-2014</Date>
            <Time>18:04:35</Time>
            <TransactionType>Funding</TransactionType>
            <TransactionStatus>Fund Success</TransactionStatus>
            <TransactionAmount>100</TransactionAmount>
            <TransactionFee>2</TransactionFee>
            <TransactionCommission>1</TransactionCommission>
            <WalletId>0003466476</WalletId>
            <UserType>Service Provider</UserType>
            <AccountType>Fee A/C</AccountType>
            <MobileNo>0000000000</MobileNo>
            <Amount>2</Amount>
            <Type>C</Type>
        </Row>
        <Row index="1">
            <TransactionId>9535789377931</TransactionId>
            <Date>17-APR-2014</Date>
            <Time>18:04:35</Time>
            <TransactionType>Funding</TransactionType>
            <TransactionStatus>Fund Success</TransactionStatus>
            <TransactionAmount>100</TransactionAmount>
            <TransactionFee>2</TransactionFee>
            <TransactionCommission>1</TransactionCommission>
            <WalletId>0007923578</WalletId>
            <UserType>Service Provider</UserType>
            <AccountType>Commission A/C</AccountType>
            <MobileNo>0000000000</MobileNo>
            <Amount>1</Amount>
            <Type>C</Type>
        </Row>
    </TransactionRowSet>    
</Report>
```

The jrxml of main report is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="TransactionReport" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="5f706135-d62b-4d94-a8ec-8d2f0d137aa9">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="Subreport_1" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"/>
    <parameter name="Subreport_2" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"/>
    <queryString language="xpath2">
        <![CDATA[/Report]]>
    </queryString>
    <detail>
        <band height="67" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="187" height="67" uuid="325d0803-5a7b-4f06-a809-8c8a3e83bf8c"/>
                <subreportParameter name="XML_DATA_DOCUMENT">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{XML_DATA_DOCUMENT}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{Subreport_1}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
        <band height="66">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="197" height="66" uuid="3064bea5-2e7f-4cfc-ae02-3745703af1b0"/>
                <subreportParameter name="XML_DATA_DOCUMENT">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{XML_DATA_DOCUMENT}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{Subreport_2}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The jrxml of sub-report 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="TransactionReport_subreport1" pageWidth="802" pageHeight="555" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="588e5172-b1db-40c6-927f-aca7a0b2876c">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="90"/>
    <queryString language="xpath2">
        <![CDATA[/Report/TransactionTypeRowSet/Row]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="runDate" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[ancestor::Report/@runDate]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="TransactionType" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[TransactionType]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="TransactionNo" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[TransactionNo]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="TotalAmount" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[TotalAmount]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="TotalFee" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[TotalFee]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="TotalCommission" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[TotalCommission]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="128" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="aa03e739-6e8c-4566-99ea-2d15b27479f3"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{runDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="10" y="0" width="45" height="20" uuid="59bf27b5-c260-4aa8-9347-f314619b73b4"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Run Date]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="22" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="10" y="2" width="100" height="20" uuid="a636f8fb-9dc5-4d5a-be72-faf2e569f1ce"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Transaction Type]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="128" y="2" width="100" height="20" uuid="066d175f-783d-46a9-bb9b-15c6740aab94"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Transaction No.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="244" y="2" width="100" height="20" uuid="20d8dbc0-d94a-4aa2-8f20-c130d5d72937"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Total Amount]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="358" y="2" width="100" height="20" uuid="1f47dc2d-5849-4440-8861-1523473b7ef7"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Total Fee]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="470" y="2" width="100" height="20" uuid="48309245-2d2a-43b4-bc10-7f91e1e64612"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Total Commission]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="10" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="44951d02-8cdb-4c98-b7d5-e58c6e46e807"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TransactionType}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="128" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="abaeec97-a833-4731-9272-4f52972a168a"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TransactionNo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="244" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="ba6461a1-0042-49ce-8cc5-fef146fd2602"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TotalAmount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="358" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="e28079e5-ad93-4c96-a030-de8da6d045e3"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TotalFee}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="470" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="4d9482db-e1dc-4e80-8547-87446e7bad0c"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TotalCommission}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

The JRXML of sub-report 2 is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="TransactionReport_subreport2" pageWidth="1500" pageHeight="555" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="1500" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="f22b3fa9-da70-48b3-a92b-7d9d5ce3c988">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <queryString language="xpath2">
        <![CDATA[/Report/TransactionRowSet/Row]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="runDate" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[ancestor::Report/@runDate]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="TransactionId" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[TransactionId]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="Date" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Date]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="Time" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Time]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="TransactionType" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[TransactionType]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="TransactionStatus" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[TransactionStatus]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="TransactionAmount" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[TransactionAmount]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="TransactionFee" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[TransactionFee]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="TransactionCommission" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[TransactionCommission]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="WalletId" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[WalletId]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="UserType" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[UserType]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="AccountType" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[AccountType]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="MobileNo" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[MobileNo]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="Amount" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Amount]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="Type" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Type]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="110" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="4290617b-8c2a-4530-b0e5-106dd9c35135"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{runDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="5" y="0" width="45" height="20" uuid="eb5b3fbe-99a8-4142-b70c-121250521ccd"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Run Date]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="22" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="5" y="2" width="100" height="20" uuid="041974c0-9b9b-47a1-86b3-3dc3ce64f70f"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Transaction Id]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="110" y="2" width="100" height="20" uuid="5c7f1106-d65e-4cca-9f82-92d7adb02a7d"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Date]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="215" y="2" width="100" height="20" uuid="29432958-c1b2-4164-a6d2-61cda5131091"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Time]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="320" y="2" width="100" height="20" uuid="b84c859b-44e2-4c58-ac50-30b6db62b752"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Transaction Type]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="425" y="2" width="100" height="20" uuid="e77d633a-d760-4f5c-8d88-95fb91afab21"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Transaction Status]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="530" y="2" width="100" height="20" uuid="0b4a24b8-2d64-42a2-9875-fd617ddf663e"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Transaction Amount]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="634" y="2" width="100" height="20" uuid="c6610ab4-f4b0-445a-8f6c-d8e123ca9562"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Fee]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="737" y="2" width="100" height="20" uuid="2446940d-ecda-47ff-90e1-1889898b8857"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Commission]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="840" y="2" width="100" height="20" uuid="902717d0-bd96-44dd-9195-ceca8d2ca466"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Wallet Id]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="943" y="2" width="100" height="20" uuid="246f09b5-f738-479b-819d-d8648f8e13a0"/>
                <text><![CDATA[User Type]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="1047" y="2" width="100" height="20" uuid="68970e38-f49c-4a9b-8bf8-486298474fff"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Account Type]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="1152" y="2" width="100" height="20" uuid="31714d60-87d2-41bd-bd74-60ea96d9adcf"/>
                <text><![CDATA[MobileNo]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="1256" y="2" width="100" height="20" uuid="609bf515-758a-4cc6-b23a-ed603f036f12"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Amount]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="1360" y="2" width="100" height="20" uuid="b8afcb53-8306-4569-8597-0f3213a09872"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Type]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="5" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="29895b19-71b2-43ec-aa18-c5d23d3cece4"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TransactionId}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="110" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="1c42caa6-a106-45ff-96ec-65b4873c016d"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="215" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="6d85cc83-3830-44af-ac6d-517bb107d3ac"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Time}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="320" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="aee3e08d-744d-4578-89da-c5296237510e"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TransactionType}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="425" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="20ca50d3-c882-43f2-b3c0-334e7b7c3206"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TransactionStatus}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="530" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="3e0418dc-e327-4d94-ac4a-831e6cfdbcde"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TransactionAmount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="634" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="ccec42b7-84e7-43ea-af56-3ee5af5b72cf"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TransactionFee}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="737" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="a18fc12e-467e-4ecc-b983-58d5eebb3bf3"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TransactionCommission}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="840" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="67a5658d-56ee-4f56-ac28-d5954febf852"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{WalletId}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="943" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="9c032b11-4fc6-4b1b-89c4-83d508db9475"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{UserType}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="1047" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="c8a4c818-6eb7-4186-b996-75b0fd9400b2"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{AccountType}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="1152" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="dd8671c2-13d1-4b7a-829d-ded93701fc13"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{MobileNo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="1256" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="48fc8c4f-014d-493c-8b75-63b60dfc7ddc"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Amount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="1360" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="006ea1f0-30a3-49b8-8c98-e5702146e9c6"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Type}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Now, how do I write the java code with XML data sources for Jasper report with sub-report?
I tried this:

```
JasperPrint print = new JasperPrint();
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
JasperDesign design, design1;
JasperReport report, report1;
JasperReport jasperReport;
JasperDesign jd1;


jd1 = JRXmlLoader.load("C:/Users/bferrao/Desktop/jasper/TransactionReport_subreport1.jrxml");
jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd1);

Map parameters = new HashMap();
parameters.put("Subreport_1", jasperReport);

design = JRXmlLoader.load("C:/Users/bferrao/Desktop/jasper/TransactionReport_subreport2.jrxml");
report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);
parameters.put("Subreport_2", report);

Document document = JRXmlUtils.parse(new File("C:/Users/bferrao/Desktop/jasper/TransactionReport.xml"));
parameters.put(JRXPathQueryExecuterFactory.PARAMETER_XML_DATA_DOCUMENT, document);

JRXmlDataSource jrxmlds = new JRXmlDataSource(new File("C:/Users/bferrao/Desktop/jasper/TransactionReport.xml"), "/Report");
design1 = JRXmlLoader.load("C:/Users/bferrao/Desktop/jasper/TransactionReport.jrxml");
report1 = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design1);
JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(report1, "C:/Users/bferrao/Desktop/jasper/master_report.jrprint", parameters, jrxmlds);

exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "D:\\temp\\Report3.pdf");
exporter.exportReport();
```

Looking at your stackoverflow I have modified my main report and java building of report. How do I pass the XML datasource? I'm still getting blank report.

Comment: Looking at your stackoverflow I have modified my main report and java building of report. How do I pass the XML datasource? I'm still getting blank report.

Comment: Just for information, in general it is better if you do not modify your initial question because the answer(s) can be totally wrong after your changes. If you want to give an update it is better to comment here (or on the answer) than changing the inital code. Otherwise (but for shorter question) you can add an "UPDATE:" section.

Answer (score 0):

In your Java code you are adding the two subReport as parameters `Subreport_1` and `Subreport_2` but the master report declares only a parameter named "SUBREPORT_DIR".

I did something similar than your Java code (summarized):

```
   // first compile the sub reports
   jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd1);
   jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd1);
   report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);

   // then add the compiled reports to your parameters
   Map parameters = new HashMap();
   parameters.put("Subreport_1", jasperReport);
   parameters.put("Subreport_2", report);

   // and finally send the sub-reports to the main report as parameters
   JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(report1, "D:/temp/master_report.jrprint", parameters, jrxmlds);
```

You have to declare the subreport as parameter like this in the master jrxml:

```
<parameter name="Subreport_1" class="java.lang.Object"/>
<parameter name="Subreport_2" class="java.lang.Object"/>

...

<subreport runToBottom="false">
    <reportElement uuid="ce3bf2a2-9131-4d75-800b-25d4a71791c3" 
         positionType="Float"    isPrintRepeatedValues="false" 
         x="0" y="179" width="468" height="28" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
    <subreportParameter name="XML_DATA_DOCUMENT">
        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{XML_DATA_DOCUMENT}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
    </subreportParameter>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{Subreport_1}]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

and the following parameter can be removed as it seems not used in your code:

```
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\bferrao\\Desktop\\jasper\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

Another thing you have to be careful is the datasource visibility in the subreport.

Comment: I added comments to your part of code, but generally I would say it is correct. I have a bit another logic as I can have an arbitrary number of sub reports. I just compile all files in a foler with a certain pattern and then add them to the parameter Map. Then I compile the master and use the FillReportToStream as I wanted to use it in another Java part. I will check later about how the datasource is transferred across the sub-reports, perhaps your problem is there as well.

Comment: @bosco1 ok, I do not have the code right now, but i will try to look into it later and update my answer. In the meantime you can check this article if it helps: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/802959/subreport-not-filled-xml-data-source-and-compilation-runtime

Comment: Looking at your stackoverflow I have modified my main report and java building of report. How do I pass the XML datasource? I'm still getting blank report.

Comment: 1st. For the queryString language I have `xPath` and not `xpath2`

Comment: Thats fine pls can you let me know how to proceed. I'm getting blank report.

Comment: Do you get any error/stacktrace ? is it generating the pdf file?

Comment: No errors or stacktrace a blank pdf file is generated.

Comment: I think you don't need the line `<connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>` if you use XML datasource. (I don't have it and it works for me)

Comment: I removed that line from main report still I get blank report. Pls can you give source code of your working version.